# Bootstrap navbar nav-item's aren't the same size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been experimenting with using the `Bootstrap` Navbar. So far I'm pretty happy with the results for my webpage's navigation. I have a lot of links and it displays them in a nice way. The only problem is that the nav links don't look evenly distributed. Here is the condensed code for the navbar. View it in full screen, otherwise the `nav-item`s stack.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class='navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-column align-items-stretch'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='navbar' id='navbarContent'>
      <div class="navbar-nav nav-fill">
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Home</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">About IGA</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">IGA Staff and Consultants</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Research</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">The Very Large Infrastructure</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Hopeful wishes and best thoughts</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Conferences and Events</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Media</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

When I add borders to the `nav-item`s, I notice that the links with longer text are wider in width. As such, links with smaller widths are grouped together.

```css
.nav-item  {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class='navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-column align-items-stretch'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='navbar' id='navbarContent'>
      <div class="navbar-nav nav-fill">
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Home</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">About IGA</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">IGA Staff and Consultants</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Research</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">The Very Large Infrastructure</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Hopeful wishes and best thoughts</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Conferences and Events</a>
        <a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Media</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to make them evenly distributed? I noticed when they're stacked and the links are each one line, they're all the same width. I think when the longer nav links are wrapped to a second line, the spacing gets messed up.

If I manually set a `max-width` on the `nav-item`, it makes the `navbar` either too wide or not wide enough. I want it to fit across the site layout, as it does without setting the `max-width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` tags do not auto expand to the correct width.
You need to surround the `<a>` tags with a `<div>` like this

```css
.nav-border {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class='navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-column align-items-stretch'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='navbar' id='navbarContent'>
      <div class="navbar-nav nav-fill">
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Home</a></div>
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">About IGA</a></div>
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">IGA Staff and Consultants</a></div>
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Research</a></div>
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">The Very Large Infrastructure</a></div>
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Hopeful wishes and best thoughts</a></div>
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Conferences and Events</a></div>
        <div class="nav-border"><a class='nav-item nav-link' href="/">Media</a></div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is a start. Thank you. On smaller screens it overflows off the navbar though (shrink the screen and you'll see)

Comment: I just added a media selector and only added the padding on large screens or larger. Thanks.

Comment: ok thats excellent it you found the final fix, good luck with your project :)